# How to write swift properties calculated in later stage of Object's lifecycle

Tags: swift

I have a swift UIViewController in which there is an array of data type ( e.g. countries/person/ bank details) fetched from network service asynchronously in viewDidLoad. This array remains constant once fetched. Hence I want to enforce it using let keyword.

I don't have any value when UIViewController is initialized. Hence it gives me compile time error for not initializing it. 
If I declare it as optional with '?' , I have to use if-let/ guard let or optional chaining to use it. I don't want to clutter the code with unwrapping.

What are my options to declare a variable as constant but initialized later in execution without making it an optional variable?

Answer (score 3):

"Constant once fetched" is not constant. There is some period of time when it's not set, and some point later when it is. The fact that it's fetched from the network means that it may fail, so your code has to deal with that (i.e. it may *never* be set). The right tool to use here is an Optional `var`.

Since there must be some view state that handles "no data yet" and a different view state that handles "data received," you can improve your design by breaking those into two view controllers, and having your container view controller switch between them when the data becomes available. In that case, you can pass the available data to the "data received" view controller in `init`, and so it can be `let`.

Answer (score 2):

> What are my options to declare a variable as constant but initialized later

There are no such options. If you do not have the real value of a property at instantiation time, it must be declared with `var` so that you can set it when you do have the real value.

And use of an Optional is a common pattern to help your code distinguish between before you have the real value (nil) and after (not nil).

> I don't want to clutter the code with unwrapping.

Then declare the property as an implicitly unwrapped Optional! This use case is *exactly* what it is good for.

(It would be nice to be able to “lock” the property somehow after assigning its final value, but that is not a Swift language feature. I have often wished it were. `lazy` has the same issue.)